# Allow Special Characters in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a VBA code that takes data from one sheet (a form) and copies it to another (a database) after you hit a button.

The problem is, if there are any special characters in this one field called "InstalDesc", the VBA code bugs out. It does allow special characters in other fields, just this one it seems to bug out.

I see tons of examples online about how to remove or replace special characters with a space or whatever, but the thing is, I don't care if they have a comma or asterisks or whatever in the form... it's fine to copy exactly what they enter in the form.

Just so we're clear, when I say "Special characters", I'm referring to the following:

! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) { [ ] } ? , - / \ < > ; : ` ~ | ' + .

So does anyone know of any code or way to tell VBA to ALLOW these characters and just copy whatever they put in?

It debugs on this line:

```
.Names.Add Name:=InstalDesc, RefersTo:=.Range("D" & n) 'create name range
```

And I have InstalDesc set to `Dim InstalDesc As String`

Comment: You are adding a *name*. A name has to conform to certain rules, otherwise it cannot be used in a formula. Even if you removed all special characters from `InstalDesc`, a name such as `"A1"` would still not be allowed because it looks like a range address. For the same reason you cannot do `Dim @#$%^&* As String` in VBA.

Comment: Oh, bugger, you're right. And I think I need it to be a name because when it pastes into the database, it created a named cell so we can quickly find it later... hmm... unless someone has any other ideas, I guess I'll just have to replace them with a space.

Comment: Spaces are [not allowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.names.add#parameters) as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "(a form)"? You should restrict the names entered by user. If such illegal characters exist in the user input, a message mentioning which are these not admitted character to be sent and **not allowing to go out from where the text is introduced (text box, cell, whatever)**, except the case when the string is correct (without such characters)... But, in order to receive more concrete help, please define what that "form" should mean, more specific **where the string in discussion is introduced**.

Comment: If you really need named ranges then you will need to create a function to "map" your `InstalDesc` value to a usable Name, following the rules here: https://bettersolutions.com/excel/named-ranges/index.htm#:~:text=Rules%20for%20Named%20Ranges,upper%20and%20lower%20case%20letters.  Maybe you don't really need the name though - what is it used for?